# Push notification Jquery mobile cordova application android, duplicate ids

Tags: php, android, mysql, cordova, push-notification

I am using [this push plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) for a Jquery (2.x), Jquery mobile (1.4.5) build with cordova  (5.1.1) aiming at android devices.

The plugin works ok and I have managed to send the user's device registration ID to my server via php into a mysql database.
Also I managed to send notiications to the registered id's via the GCM Google service succesfully.

the code I am using to do this is:

```
var app = {

initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},

bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},

onDeviceReady: function() {
    var push = PushNotification.init({
        "android": {
            "senderID": "xxxxxxxxx"
        },
        "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, 
        "windows": {} 
    });

    push.on('registration', function(data) {
        console.log("registration event");
        var gcm_regid = data.registrationId;
        $.post('http://xxxxx.xxx/insert.php', {gcm_regid: gcm_regid});
 return false;
    });
```

and the insert.php is

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","gcm","password");
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("gcm", $con);
$gcm_regid=$_POST['gcm_regid'];

  $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO gcm_users(gcm_regid) VALUES('$gcm_regid')");
     if($query){
  echo "Data for $gcm_regid inserted successfully!";
  }
 else{ echo "An error occurred!"; }
  ?>
```

My SQL database has the structure:

```
id  -> int(11) -->  AUTO_INCREMENT
gcm_regid   text  
created_at -->  timestamp -> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

The problem is that whenever the user starts the application on his device the registration id is send again into the mysql database, thus creating duplicate entries for the same registrationId.

How can I prevent this from happening?

How can I prevent the device to send the id again into the database?
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to partially solve my own problem by altering my sql database
to  `gcm_regid` --> `VARCHAR` and by executing the following to my database

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE gcm_users
ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (gcm_regid);
```

now each time a duplicate `gcm_regid` is inserted, it is automatically rejected by the database.

This is clearly not the best solution, but I hope someone has a better way...

Answer (score 0):

I do it by saving the device.uuid variable as well. So this is a unique userid by device and you can insert into your sql query WHERE uuid = device.uuid and you can update if exists or insert if not. I hope this help.